# Accessing data from a closed Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get email addresses from another file onto the active workbook that is being used, however I only need certain email addresses based on a region that is in the file that we get every morning. I'm currently wondering if there is a way to grab these email addresses without having to open the email list as that dictates whether the vlookup works?

The code is as follows:

```
Sub Vlookup_DoWhile()

 Dim LookupRange As Range
 Dim Cll As Range
 Dim myRange As Range
 Dim i As Long
 Set LookupRange = Workbooks("Email List.xlsx").Sheets(1).Range("A2:B5")


 i = 2

 Do While ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PAV").Cells(i, 15).Value > 1

 Cells(i, 16).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 15), LookupRange, 2, False)

 Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show Cells(i, 16).Value


 i = i + 1

 Loop

 End Sub
```

Comment: If it's not open, you cannot read it. But you can open it, read it, and then close it right away...

Comment: If you have the option, using a database would be much better...

Comment: @braX I mean in theory you could unzip the file, and read the data out of the xml :P

Comment: i suppose you *can* - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53049541/read-data-from-a-closed-excel-workbook - but why would you want to? What would be the benefit?

Comment: Thanks to both for the reply. I will have to look into all of this.

Comment: @braX the only database i have access to is Microsoft Access. If that is adequate then i will look into that. Do you think that could work?

Comment: Access would be perfect. And if you prefer SQL Server, you can download a free version called SQL Server Express - where the only limit is the size of the database being 10GB, which would still be more than you would probably ever need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

Sub adoDBConnection

Dim con as Object

Set con = createObject("adodb.connection")

Dim strCon as string

'IMEX =1 to read and 0 to read and write

strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"

con.open strCon

Range("A1").copyFromRecordSet con.Execute ("SELECT * [Mysheet$] WHERE [MYFIELD] = 'myvalue';"

' or to retrieve just one single value

Range("A1").value2 = con.Execute("SELECT [MYFIELD] FROM [Mysheet$] WHERE [MYFIELD2] = 'MYQUERY';)(0).value

con.close

End Sub

Comment: Ok thanks for this, ill try to incorporate with what im doing now. I appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with SQL queries I would recommend using ADODB connection. It is very fast. It doesn't flicker Excel and you dont need to open the file.

Comment: Unfortunately i am not and i don't have the access to that. I do have the ability to use Microsoft access if that is adequate???

Comment: You dont need Access, actually excel is treated as a database.